# Can random events kill your last remaining crew member?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If you only have one crew member left, can he be killed by events that kill one random crew member? Or does FTL make sure events always leave you with at least one person to play captain (allowing you to "predict the outcome" of those scenarios)?

By that I mean scenarios like [*Giant Alien Spiders*](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_Alien_Spiders) in which a random crew member gets killed instantly; not events such as an enemy boarding the ship and killing your crew member through standard combat.

Comment: Giant alien spiders are never a joke.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, crewmembers can be killed at any point, including in those types of encounters. There is no mercy for being the last crewmember, their life is just as much at risk as any others.

Generally I tend to avoid those enounters when a blue option isn't present, as the loss of a crewmember can be a pretty big setback in general, not just on your last crewmember.

Source: Personal Experience

Comment: Of course, if your ship is swimming with crew, it can be worth it, but even then you may still lose the max-combat Mantis instead of the useless human.

Comment: Normally I'm skeptical, but since you are a man of 5k+ reputation, I am going to trust your _personal experience_ source.

Comment: Not only can events kill your last remaining crew member, but you can off him/her yourself through dumb decisions.  In one game, facing a slaver ship, I only had one crew member, but I decided to offer a crew member to the slaver just to see what would happen.  Well...just what did I *think* would happen?  The crewman went over to the slavers, and as my ship had no more crew, my game immediately ended.

Comment: In one of my saddest endings, I escaped a brutal fight after losing all but 1 crew member, down to 1 health bar, with little fuel and no missiles remaining. I was debating whether to press forward, when at the very next beacon, my final crew member was kidnapped by pirates - Game Over. I knew I wasn't getting much further, but boy, I didn't expect *that*.